# Angular2 - Reference error when splitting application in different files

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript1.5

I am trying to modularize an Angular 2 application, having the services in a different file:

**app.ts**

```
/// <reference path="typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./services.ts" />

import {Component, View, bootstrap, NgFor} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  appInjector: [Service.TechnologiesService]
})
@View({
  templateUrl: 'index-angular',
  directives:[NgFor]
})

class MyAppComponent {
  name: string;
  technologies: Array<string>;

  constructor(technologiesService: Service.TechnologiesService) {
    this.name = 'DopAngular';
    this.technologies = technologiesService.technologies;
  }
}

bootstrap(MyAppComponent);
```

**services.ts**

```
module Service{
  export class TechnologiesService {
    technologies: Array<string>;
    constructor() {
      this.technologies = ['Angular 2 Developer Preview', 'Express', 'Jade', 'Gulp', 'Material Design Lite', 'Polymer', 'Sass', 'Karma', 'Mocha', 'Should', 'npm', 'Bower'];
    }
  }
}
```

These files compile to js without error, but when running the app in the browser I get:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Service is not defined`

Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I finally managed to make it work:

Modified **services.ts** (now exporting the service and not using the module keyword:

```
export class TechnologiesService {
  technologies: Array<string>;
  constructor() {
    this.technologies = ['Angular 2 Developer Preview', 'Express', 'Jade', 'Gulp', 'Material Design Lite', 'Polymer', 'Sass', 'Karma', 'Mocha', 'Should', 'npm', 'Bower'];
  }
}
```

Assuming a public resources folder for compiled js files with this hierarchy:

```
|--angular
     |----app.js
     |----services.js
```

The import sequence should be:

```
/// <reference path="typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="services.ts" />
import {Component, View, bootstrap, NgFor} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {TechnologiesService} from 'angular/services'
```

Answer (score 2):

`/// <reference path="./services.ts" />` lets the compiler see the type information of the referenced file but does not cause any code from the target to be generated/included. (This feature is mainly designed for external/ambient libraries.)

For referencing other TS files from your own code, you should use the `import {...} from 'file';` syntax (see the [handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules)), e.g.

```
import {Service} from 'services'
```

You'll also need to configure a module loader (SystemJS or requireJS) in the TS compiler config and in the browser.

Alternatively, you can do an unscalable hack by including the compiled version of `services.ts` in a `<script>` tag before that of `app.ts` and keep the code the same.

Also note: the internal module you put in `services.ts` is a bad pattern and the keyword is deprecated. See the handbook linked above.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reference statement is just going to provide the TS compiler the type information but is not going to include any code. Therefore it might autocomplete in the IDE and compile, but it will not generate anything in the .js generated by the typescript compiler. Therefore you would need to import your service such as :

```
import {TechnologiesService} from 'services';
```

Comment: When I import the service I get the following error: `TS2306: File 'C:/Users/someuser/git/myproject/resources/angular/services.ts' is not an external module.`